# trim the first few characters of string in BigQuery MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, google-bigquery, substring, trim

I need to grab the first few letters from the strings in BigQuery table. My data looks like this:

```
name
HDM | kjfsgjfgusgff
GHN | hgfhgfhgsf
GHT | 57fhjsfhjsgfghg
```

The desired output is: `HDM`, `GHN`, `GHT`
I have tried the following:

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '|', 1) as `new_name`
```

Got an error: `Function not found: substring_index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BigQuery - use below

```
select trim(split(name, '|')[offset(0)])
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your have several options depending on the shape of your data.
The TRIM + SPLIT option suggested by Mikhail, which is very close to what you tried

```
SELECT TRIM(SPLIT(name, "|")[offset(0)])
FROM table
```

The LEFT option maybe the easiest (only if there is a fixed character length that you're interested in:

```
SELECT LEFT(name,3)
FROM table
```

The regex option too if you need more precise control:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(name, r"^([A-Z]+)(?:|)")
FROM table
```

EDIT:

And Sergey's SUBSTR solution:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(name, 1, 3)
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [substr](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#substr):

```
select substr(name, 1, 3) as new_name from mytable
```